# Get UTC from another timezone with Carbon

Tags: php, php-carbon

How do I get the UTC date with [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) if I use another timezone?

```
$timestamp = '2014-02-06 16:34:00';
Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp)->timezone('Europe/Stockholm');
```

I create with a `Europe/Stockholm` timezone. How do I get the UTC date from that (2014-02-06 15:34)?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can change the timezone with this:

```
$timestamp = '2014-02-06 16:34:00';
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp, 'Europe/Stockholm');
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
```

Comment: Or use the shorthand: `$date->tz('UTC')`

Comment: :]  Or the property `$date->tz = 'UTC'`

Comment: @Till consider adding your comment as an answer.

Comment: I think that use more verbose, makes the code more readable. So I prefer the full word.

Comment: this finally saved me to fix a backlog issue since last year :D finally!!