# Format time using Carbon in 24 Hour Format (military time)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, web

I need to subtract time on my WebApp and upload it to the database.  so I want to use a 24 hour time so i wont get negative values. so here is my Code

```
        $mydate=Carbon::now()->subHours(8);
        $newdate=$mydate->toDateString();

        DB::table('attendances')->insert(
        array('user_id' => $userinput, 'logon' =>$mydate,'date_only' =>$newdate, 'in_out' =>'1')
```

Comment: Why do you have the ->subHours(8) in your code? I suggest that you want to convert the time to 'UTC' and an 'offset'. Then it can be easily processed into 'local time format'. 'UTC' is 'Military time' (Zulu).

Comment: I use sub8 for me to have the correct time, anyways what i really want to do is to get a 24 hour time

Comment: Maybe useful: [21607236/get-utc-from-another-timezone-with-carbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607236/get-utc-from-another-timezone-with-carbon)

Comment: Maybe useful: [simonholywell.com/post/2013/12/convert-utc-to-local-time.html](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2013/12/convert-utc-to-local-time.html) Also the other way: [questions/2095703/php-convert-datetime-to-utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095703/php-convert-datetime-to-utc)