# Discrepancy in timezone between Carbon and PHP's date function

Tags: php, php-carbon

When I execute `Carbon::now('US/Eastern')` I get the following from a var_dump:

```
object(Carbon\Carbon)[559]
  public 'date' => string '2014-12-15 21:52:54.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'US/Eastern' (length=10)
```

This is what I am expecting.

When I execute `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', Carbon::now('US/Eastern')->timestamp)` I get the following:

```
string '2014-12-16 02:52:54' (length=19)
```

The timezone is being ignored in the timestamp here.

Why do the date and time differ between each?

How can I get an accurate timestamp into the `date` function that reflects the timezone?

Comment: The US/Eastern timezone is deprecated. Try using America/New_York instead. Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php

Comment: Are you sure that the timestmap isn't returning something other than an integer, or is not returning false? Because if not, then the 2nd argument will be ignored and `time()` will be used.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy It is returning a timestamp integer.

Comment: Can you take the timestamp integer it provides and hard code it into the 2nd argument and see if it produces the same?

Comment: @akanevsky Using "America/New_York" did not change anything.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yep, when I drop in `1418699862` I get the exact same result.

Comment: I'm extremely confused. can you please use `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` before the `date()` call and see if it has any effect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66954/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-ecomevo).

Comment: @Ohgodwhy After doing `date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');` the date/time is correct. However, I have to change the timezone multiple times throughout the code, so having to change the default timezone each time is clunky.

Comment: @eComEvo, instead of setting default timezone in each script, you could just set it in a configuration file and then include that configuration file in each script. If you need to shift between different timezones in one script, then resetting default timezone can lead to bugs. Maybe you could instead use UTC/GMT, and then make a custom function or method that will convert the timestamp from UTC/GMT to proper timezone. Edit: Carbon supports timezone conversion - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607236/get-utc-from-another-timezone-with-carbon